# Mod-rewrite 500 Internal server error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using CodeIgniter and I already know that the production server doesn't let me use `AllowOverride ALL`. I also tried `AllowOverride Nonfatal=All`, but it doesn't help.
This my .htaccess file is in *domains/probasketpicks.com/public_html/basketball/*

```
<Directory>
        AllowOverride Nonfatal=All
</Directory>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /basketball/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Look at the error log of your webserver.

Comment: My guess would be that the `<Directory>` directive is not allowed in a .htaccess.

Comment: Error log:
[Thu Jun 12 11:16:19 2014] [alert] [client 5.20.177.34] /home/sprinter/domains/probasketpicks.com/public_html/basketball/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Jun 12 11:16:19 2014] [error] [client 5.20.177.34] File does not exist: /home/sprinter/domains/probasketpicks.com/public_html/500.shtml

Comment: "<Directory> directive is not allowed" - how should I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directives `<Directory>` and `AllowOverride` are not allowed in a .htaccess file.

The whole point of AllowOverride is to define what you can use in a .htaccess. If you could change this in the .htaccess itself it would make the directive completely useless.

Remove the directives from your .htaccess file.

Comment: Now I'm getting empty web page.
And error log is:
[Thu Jun 12 12:06:00 2014] [error] [client 5.20.177.34] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/sprinter/domains/probasketpicks.com/public_html/basketball/application/controllers/basketball.php on line 11

Could you help me to solve this?

Comment: Create a new question for your new problem. Or just solve it ... the question will most probably be closed because the solution is already in your error message.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wouldn't ever thought that something wrong with my controller file, just thought that Error log gives incorrect information. Thanx for solving both problems.